# How to map a C# model to a list of a different structure

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a model I bind json email data to (from, to , cc, bcc, etc) and the model is of this form:

```
    public class Email
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> To { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Cc { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Bcc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

However, to actually send email data from MS Graph API you need to convert it to a different form completely in a list as shown below:

```
                var message = new Message
                {
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                    {
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "email@email.com",
                                Name = "Joen Doe",
                            },
                        },
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = "email2@email.com",
                                Name = "Jane Dane",
                            },
                        },
                    }
                };
```

So how would I go about dynamically mapping the model lists to this form? I will have to use this same approach for both cc and bcc but I am not able to nest a foreach loop inside the brackets so would I just create lists outside and assign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a list before creating the message, and populate it from each of your lists:

```
public static Message ToMessage(this Email email){

    var recipients = new List<Recipient>();
    foreach(var to in email.To){
       recipients.Add(new Recipient(){ Address = to.EmailAddress});
    }
    foreach(var to in email.Cc ){
       recipients.Add(new Recipient(){ Address = to.EmailAddress}); 
    }
    foreach(var to in email.Bcc){
       recipients.Add(new Recipient(){ Address = to.EmailAddress}); 
    }

    var message = new Message(){
        Subject = email.Subject(),
        Body = email.Body(),
        ToRecipients   = recipients ,
    }
    return message;
}
```

You will ofc need to add CC/BCC/attachments etc. I have not bothered looking up the exact property names for your library. It is also likely you could create the message first, and add recipients directly to the `message.ToRecipients` property, but check the documentation for your library.

Comment: This was actually the approach I took. I had to split it up a bit more since they have their own objects for each recipient but none the less this answer is correct. Thanks!